# From raw pointers to std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I had these two functions in my project:

```
char* V8StringToChar(v8::Handle<v8::String> str);
char* V8StringToChar(v8::Local<v8::Value> val);
```

I converted them to:

```
template <class T>
class ArrayDeleter {
public:
    void operator () (T* d) const
    { delete [] d; }
};
std::shared_ptr<char> V8StringToChar(v8::Handle<v8::String> str);
std::shared_ptr<char> V8StringToChar(v8::Local<v8::Value> val);
```

with body as

```
std::shared_ptr<char> V8StringToChar(Handle<String> str) {
  int len = str->Utf8Length();
  char* buf = new char[len + 1];
  str->WriteUtf8(buf, len + 1);
  return std::shared_ptr<char>(buf, ArrayDeleter<char>());
}
std::shared_ptr<char> V8StringToChar(Local<Value> val) {
  return V8StringToChar(val->ToString());
}
```

And every usage of them to `(&*V8StringToChar(whatever))`.

And it build perfectly.

And it is causing run time errors.

Is there any cases where this could fail And please provide some good solution ?

Comment: Use vector<char> for an array of bytes.

Comment: The standard already provides an array deleter, use `std::default_delete<char[]>` (note the `[]` characters to specify an array, so it uses `delete[]`)

Comment: Probably because `&*` gives you a raw pointer, which can be invalidated when the array is deleted - in your example, that happens immediately, before you can do anything with the pointer. Only do that when your really need a raw pointer, and be very careful to ensure that nothing keeps hold of the pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of

```
(&*V8StringToChar(whatever))
```

you could have written:

```
V8StringToChar(whatever).get()
```

But both are probably wrong and guaranteed to fail in some circumstances.

Doing that creates a new buffer, returns it as a `shared_ptr`, gets the address of the buffer, then the `shared_ptr` goes out of scope and the buffer is deleted, leaving you with a dangling pointer.  Boom, any attempt to access the memory at that address is undefined behaviour. Go to jail, go directly to jail, do not pass go, do not collect £200.

I would make your functions return a `std::unique_ptr<char[]>` instead, because that has built-in support for arrays.

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> V8StringToChar(Handle<String> str) {
  int len = str->Utf8Length();
  std::unique_ptr<char[]> buf(new char[len + 1]);
  str->WriteUtf8(buf.get(), len + 1);
  return buf;
}
std::unique_ptr<char[]> V8StringToChar(Local<Value> val) {
  return V8StringToChar(val->ToString());
}
```

To fix the run-time failures you must keep the smart pointer around as long as the buffer is needed e.g.

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> smartptr = V8StringToChar(whatever);
char* ptr = smartptr.get());
doSomethingWithPtr(ptr);
// now it's OK if `smartptr` goes out of scope
```

Comment: if i do V8StringToChar(whatever).get() everywhere that should be fine too ? But its not working yet.

Comment: @Jonathan Wakely Would V8StringToChar(whatever).get() is right ?

Comment: @ASHISHNEGI, No, that is wrong too! I said _"But both are probably wrong and guaranteed to fail in some circumstances."_  Please try to understand the problem I described (and Mike Seymour described in his comment above): the smart pointer goes out of scope and so deletes the buffer at the end of the statement.

Comment: @Jonathan Wakely I mean after using your solution unique_ptr<char[]> if i do use .get() like some_other_func(V8StringToCHar(..).get()) <- is it wrong ?

Comment: **YES IT'S STILL WRONG**. The solution is shown at the end of my answer where I say _"To fix the run-time failures"_, did you read that part?! Just switching to `unique_ptr` and using `.get()` doesn't address the problem of the smart pointer going out of scope. Please try to understand the problem and engage brain.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I have read your answer and i understand it but can you please explain in your answer -> if i do pass that pointer to some other function like some_other_func(V8StringToCHar(whatever).get()) that uses it and when that function returns, only then this temp copy would be destroyed. If i am not saving that copy in some other variable, i could not use it and i then should not care.  If it would Fail and please explain why not yours fail. May be i am missing something.

Comment: I got it finally, very slow learner. after the unique_ptr.get() function returns that temp copy of unique_ptr gets out of scope.

Comment: If you are not definitely saving it in some other variable then it should work, but the fact you're getting run-time errors after making that change indicates you are using the pointer after the `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr` has gone out of scope